# How to access WooCommerce product attribute variations in a template

Tags: woocommerce, attributes, product-variations

I have created `single-product.php` which is used as a template to display my product name, description, price, picture and add to basket link.

However I now have a product which includes variations. The attribute set is called `sizes` and contains the terms `Large`, `Medium`, `Small`.

How can I access these to populate a `<select>` or radio button set and enable the user to add to basket?

EDIT: I have tried `$product->get_attribute( 'sizes' )` but that simply shows the labels i.e. "Large". I require the IDs for populating the select box values.

Answer (score 2):

Can this help you?

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Attribute.html

```php
// Get Product Variations - WC_Product_Attribute Object
$product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();

// For debug, delete afterwards
echo '<pre>', print_r($product_attributes, 1), '</pre>';

// Not empty, contains values
if ( !empty( $product_attributes ) ) {

    foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute ) {
        // Get name
        $product_attribute->get_name();

        // Get id
        $product_attribute->get_id();

        // Get options
        $product_attribute->get_options();
    }
}
```